# What component allows DIP to be connected with Dupont style jumper wires?

Tags: integrated-circuit, connector, dip, jumper

(sorry for the n00b/cringey question!) I've order an ADC chip and I realized upon receiving it that standard Dupont style jumper wires don't fit on standard integrated chips pins.  I was wondering if an IC to jumper wire connector/socket even exists and if so, then what it's called.

Basically, what I'm aiming for is a single component that combines a DIP socket (at least 2x8 pins) and Dupont style jump wire header pins so that I can push my IC in that socket and connect jumper wires without any soldering.

The closest I could find is this guy who made himself a couple ones with breadboard, but does that exist as a single standard component?

Thx

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't that be a breadboard?

Comment: As I wrote in the last sentence: Does that exist as a single component?

Comment: Can you still get wirewrap sockets?

Comment: On chinese market, they seem non existent whatsoever.  Looks like a thing of the past indeed! It's sad, because I see fit in many hobby projects.  At least, I find a DIP socket to be much quicker/better than fiddling with a big piece of breadboard.

Comment: Look into a Digikey board #V1019-ND. Vector board #3677. 3 holes per pad plus gnd and Vcc traces. About $60 USD. 4.5" x 9.6". .042" holes, not plated through, but save a lot of manual wiring. Holes are .1" centers.

Comment: While solutions exist, connecting an IC on the end of jumper wires is generally a bad idea; **when that chip is an ADC, it is an extremely bad idea**.  You really need a circuit board with good grounding, supply bypassing, decoupling of analog supplies and reference from digital noise sources, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've noticed with a stakable header that the connection was somewhat loose and that it would only work when I pressed a little bit on the sides, so indeed, it's a bad idea, also I realized how sensitive MCP3008 really is: If I put my finger just NEAR the hot wire (3.3v) the ADC begins supplying values, like WTF... it's picking up my NON TOUCHING finger resistance.

Comment: Yes, "hand capacitance" is a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look into wire wrap sockets which look like this[image]

Or you could use a breadboard:
[image]
If you are ok with using jumper cables with one end having a male pin, you can push your IC into the breadboard and use your jumpers to connect to it. Breadboards are pretty standard for electronics prototyping, and typically people plug their components into them and use short jumpers to make connections where required.

Comment: I do not want to use a breadboard for this.  I'm looking for a single component that allows me to use DIP with female Dupont jumper wires and it seems your first sentence is what I need, but are you sure the spacing is standard for jumper wires and DIP's? Also, is there a name or is it just called "wire wrap sockets"? Thx!

Comment: The spacing is 2.54mm or 0.1in, same as standard male headers. Yes, they're just called wire wrap sockets

Comment: Why are wire wrap sockets holes round? Will the DIP chip snugly fit in there as opposed to DIP sockets which have plier style holes? e.g.: https://dojft4652t1in.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/CN-IC-1403.jpg

Comment: Yes, the round holes will work. The sockets are designed to accept standard DIP ICs

Comment: Do you know where I can order a piece for less than 133$ ? WTF... http://oi68.tinypic.com/2dl8y1k.jpg

Comment: mouser search, there's 14 pin sockets for around $3.50 each: https://www.mouser.com/Connectors/IC-Component-Sockets/_/N-211lkZ1yzvvqx?P=1z0xbojZ1z0z24i

Comment: Needed 16 pins for 8 bit DIP (8 x 2 = 16 pins) and shipping is 20$ for a single piece! 23.54$ for a socket? Are you kidding me? I ended up picking up 2 arduino stackable header pieces for a grand total of 1.20$ at my local electronics surplus store.  23.54$ FOR A DIP SOCKET, WTF?

Comment: Where do you live? It’s $5 for shipping in the US

Comment: In Canada, see my previous screenshot for a whopping 133$ A PIECE on another US website! http://oi68.tinypic.com/2dl8y1k.jpg

Comment: @that-ben wire wrap isn't really an actively used technology anymore, so mainline vendors are likely going to charge a lot to stock rarely needed components - the only place you are likely to get a good deal is a surplus vendor, hamfest, etc.  Female headers probably won't do a good job of holding DIP IC leads.   None of these solutions are sensible for an ADC anyway; you really need the supporting circuitry to be right at the IC, not remoted on wires.